# Phrasal Verbs, how is it work?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> Her hair peeked **out** under the brim.

Why it is wrong if I leave *out* from that sentence?

> She walked **along** the bank

Why it is wrong if I say "she walked on the bank"?

As an English learner, what is the best way to learn these phrasal verbs? Is there any other way to understand phrasal verbs other than by memorizing it?

*PS: Please correct my sentences if it's grammatically wrong. Thank you!*

Comment: The best way to learn them is to memorize them as if they were completely new verbs.  But not every combination is a phrasal verb.  Some are just the usual verb plus some adverb or preposition. "Walk along" is not a phrasal verb.  It's the usual meaning of "walk" plus an adverb of location.

Comment: Both of those convey a limitation on direction relative to the object. if I saw someone wearing a brimmed hat, and peaked under it, I'd be looking in at them, and they'd be looking out at me. in the case of the bank, it implies that they are walking parallel to the bank, and will not enter the water, or leave the edge of the water while walking.

Comment: If you said *her hair peeked under the brim* it would mean *her hair looked under the brim*, as if *her hair* could see. As Andrew said above, phrasal verbs are best treated as new verbs - so *peeked* and *peeked out* have different meanings. It is confusing because if you say *she peeked out of the window*, that is the verb *peeked* plus *out of the window*, and not the phrasal verb *peeked out* plus *of the window*. Just because you see verb + particle, it doesn't mean you are looking at a phrasal verb - unfortunately it's more complicated than that.

Comment: There is nothing *ungrammatical* about leaving out the prepositions. But the meaning of the sentences will change if you omit them. (And, in many cases, to something that would normally be considered nonsensical.)